# Set proxy settings and proxy authentication

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, powershell, proxy

I'm new to `PowerShell`, and I'm tired of changing `proxy settings` and `proxy authentication` every time I go to the university, is there a way to do that using PowerShell Commands , like using PowerShell script to enter the proxy address and the port and the authentication, instead of using the graphical windows `InternetOptions>Connections>LanSettings` (I assume that exists), if yes how can I do it?

I've searched the web and StackOverflow but I had different answers that didn't target what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested, so I wrote a little POSH CmdLet that should help. There were plenty of references via a search on Google for how to do this so the information was there. Most of the solutions I found weren't really in the standard Powershell coding convention so I couldn't help myself. Try this out. This does nothing for the "Automatically Detect Settings". You are on your own for that one. This does however Enable/Disable proxy settings:

```
function Modify-ProxySettings() {
    [CmdLetBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$True)]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)][String]$Proxy,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)][String]$Port,
        [ValidateSet("Disable","Enable")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$Action
    )
    Begin {
        $RegKey = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
        if ($Action.Equals("Enable") -and ([String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Proxy) -and [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Port))) {
            throw New-Object System.Exception "Proxy and Port must be defined when enabling"
        }
    }
    Process {
        if ($Action.Equals("Enable")) {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name ProxyEnable -Value 1 
            Write-Verbose -Message "Set: $RegKey\ProxyEnable to Enabled(1)"
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name ProxyServer -Value "$Proxy`:$Port"
            Write-Verbose -Message "Set: $RegKey\ProxyServer to $Proxy`:$Port"
            Write-Host "Proxy Enabled with $Proxy`:$Port"
        } elseif ($Action.Equals("Disable")) {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name ProxyEnable -Value 0
            Write-Verbose -Message "Set: $RegKey\ProxyEnable to Disabled(0)"
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $RegKey -Name ProxyServer -Value ""
            Write-Verbose -Message "Proxy server and port removed"
            Write-Host "Proxy Disabled" 
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
Modify-ProxySettings -Action Disable #Disables

Modify-ProxySettings -Action Enable -Proxy someproxy.com -Port 1337 #Enables
```

Some validation catches:

- Action is mandatory and only takes "Disable" or "Enable". Use tab completion for simplicity
- Proxy and Port are required if "Enable" is chosen

Comment: A gotcha: Proxy settings are initialized when wininet layer is loaded, so these won't take effect immidiently. You can create an iexplore com object and destroy it to force the wininet layer reload.